# Injecting form options and input tags from the model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-models, modular-design

How do I add options and fields to my form generated by a builder with `form_for @user` in the model? (ie. without touching the HTML)

The reason I want to do that is that I am adding a pluggable module to my model, and I want it to automatically (a) add a `data` attribute in the HTML to provide a hook for the Javascript, and (b) add an extra field in the form.

For example adding such a module to my model:

```
module Dataable
  def form_options
    { 'data-foo' => true }
  end

  def form_builder_extra_fields
    hidden_field_tag :the_data
  end
end

User.send :include, Dataable
```

would make `form_for` to output:

```
<form {...} data-foo>
  <input type="hidden" name="user[the_data]" {...} />
  {...}
</form>
```

in the view.

Of course those methods I've just made up. The question is thus two-fold; how to add (1) form options and (2) form tags dynamically in the model.

I am in the process of prying `form_for` right now, but I wonder if anybody knew.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand what you're trying to do. If all you want to do carry some info from the controller to the form, so that it's submitted later, and using the User as a passenger.

Controller

```
@user.new
@user.whatever = 'stuff'
```

View

```
= form_for @user do |f|
  = hidden_tag 'user[whatever]', value: @user.whatever
```

---

If you're repeating it over and over again, and want it in the model

Model

```
def add_data
  self.whatever = 'stuff'
end
```

Controller

```
@user.new
@user.add_data()
```

Comment: The goal is not having to modify the view whether the module is included or not. So not including the module in the model would not make the hidden tag appear. The hidden tag would be added dynamically via module.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: `form_for` is a helper, and the rational thing to do would be to override it with a helper. I'm unsure if I'm at the right level of abstraction, but for now, it's what seems to work.

The helper will call `acts_like?` to determine if the module has been included.

```
module UsersHelper
  def form_for_users(options = {}, &block)
    if @user.acts_like? :dataable
      options.deep_merge!({ html: { 'data-foo' => true } })

      new_block = Proc.new do |builder|
        content = capture(builder, &block)

        output = ActiveSupport::SafeBuffer.new
        output.safe_concat(tag :input, {type: 'hidden', name: 'user[the_data]'})
        output << content
      end
    else
      new_block = block
    end

    form_for(@user, options, &new_block)
  end
end
```

Happy monkeypatching!